# mongoose: getting unknown objectId when stored string instead of objectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

According to me when i pushed 'ABC' instead of objectId, It should show some error like

> **Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ABC" at path "likes"**.

but when i print that updated data i saw some unknown objectId in likes array

My question is, what is that unknown objectId(6a61736f6e20626f75726e65) and why it is generated
automatically 
User Model

```
  new Schema({
            name: { type: String,required:true},
    }, { usePushEach: true ,timestamp:true});
```

Feed Model

```
new Schema({
        user: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: true },
        name: { type: String,default:null, trim: true },
        likes: [{ type : Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user',}],
}, { usePushEach: true ,timestamp:true});
```

---

In Feed Schema likes have reference to User Schema

```
var data = await feed.findByIdAndUpdate(
                 postId, 
                { 
                 $push: { likes: 'ABC' }
                }
           );




        if(data){
         var data = await feed.findById(postId);
         console.log(data.likes);//["6a61736f6e20626f75726e65"]
        }
        OutPut:
        ["6a61736f6e20626f75726e65"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pushing a `String` in `likes` which is not an `ObjectId`, you are getting this error.

Your schema clearly states that likes is an `array of ObjectId`:

```
likes: [{ type : Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'}],
```

so you have to pass an `ObjectId` instead of user's `name`.

You have to do this:

```
// Whenever you are pushing value in `likes` `array`, 
// you need to get the `ObjectId` of the user who liked the feed.

let userId =  <userId_of_Ishwar>;
var data = await feed.findByIdAndUpdate(
     postId, 
     { 
         $push: { likes: userId }
     });
```

Comment: I asked why unknown objectId automatically generated when i pushed string

Comment: I know i have to pass objectId there,

Comment: Im sorry i misread the question, but `findOneAndUpdate` doesn't return updated object, unless `{new : true}` is passed as/in options. So i guess, the ID you are printing is what is already present there before the update. you can validate that by doing `.find()` before and after `.findOneAndUpdate()`